# Tabulator / Mutator and condition not running

Tags: javascript, tabulator

My goal is to run the mutator in Tabulator to update the value to a link if a condition is met. I've included a sample at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/philippatel/m520dpyt/59/). It seems the mutator does not run when the table is created. I've added logs and none appear in the console. The javascript example is

```
//Sample Data
var tableData = [
    {name:"Bob"},
    {name:"Steve",link:"https://example.org"},
    {name:"Jim"},
]

//Example Table
var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
  data: tableData, //load data into table
  height: 200, //enable the virtual DOM
  columns: [{
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    width: 300,
    mutator: certificateMutator,
    mutatorParams: {
      certLink: "https://example.org"
    },
  }, ]
});

var certificateMutator = function(value, data, type, params, component) {
  try {
    //let cert = params;
    console.log('here');
    if (value == 'Steve') {
      let cert = mutatorParams.certLink;
      let certLink = document.createElement('a');
      certLink.href = cert;
      certLink.target = '_blank';
      certLink.innerText = 'Certificate for' + value;
      console.log(certLink);
      return certLink;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
    //return value > mutatorParams.certLink;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('certificateMutator err: ' + err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the mutator function to a variable (`certificateMutator`) AFTER creating the table.

You can either declare the mutator variable before the table:

```
var certificateMutator = function(value, data, type, params, component) { ... }

var table = new Tabulator("#table", { ... })
```

or, even better, declare `certificateMutator` as a function instead of a variable and the placement before or after the table won't matter:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#table", { ... })

function certificateMutator(value, data, type, params, component) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the second option. I did find one bug in the documentation. When passing parameters, it should be function certificateMutator(value, data, type, **mutatorParams**, component)